# Inconsistent Android Performance

Tags: android, emulation

I'm currently running two emulators on two different computers. Both emulators are running the same application.

Specs for Computer A:

```
 Processor - Intel Core i5 3230M CPU @ 2.60 GHz
 RAM - 6.00 GB (5.89 GB)
 System - 64 bit
```

This computer runs two servers EasyPHP, Openfire, and a web browser.

Specs for Computer B:

```
 Processor - Intel Core i5 2320M CPU @ 3.00 GHz
 RAM - 6.00 GB (5.89 GB)
 System - 64 bit
```

This computer does not run much, other than android studio and the emulator.

Computer A is extremely laggy and experiences high values of

```
           Skipped 516 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Computer B on the other hand not only boots the emulator faster but the application performances smoothly. Computers B application has more View objects than Computer As. I have tried using TraceView, but the output does not give me anything useful concerning the application. It mostly outs long run time for O.S functions such as Android.os.MessageQueue.nativepollOnce, Android.view.ThreadedRenderer and the like.

If the problem is a code and or view issue then why is Computer B not experiencing poor performance? Is there another way, other than TraceView/sysTrace, that measures code performance? Does using AsyncTask hurt performance more than a normal thread does? (I've been hesitant on using normal threads due to manual thread management)

Comment: You have not provided any information about what other processes are running on these 2 computers.  The fact that computer A runs the app slower cannot be deemed a problem with this limited information.

Comment: Computer A runs two servers EasyPHP, openfire, and web browser. Computer B only runs android studio and the emulator.

Comment: It is possible that the server processes on A are consuming significant CPU.  Also there are likely many more processes running on these systems.

Comment: My suggestion is to run on actual devices rather than an emulator. The provided emulator is notorious for performance issues. I personally like to run on both a newer device and an older device so that I can see the performance of the app on both. This will give you a much better idea of what the end user will actually experience. If you are still experiencing lag, there are a lot of ways to optimize your code for performance. Hunting down memory leaks and minimizing virtual method calls come to mind, but a quick youtube search will find you a lot of discussions on the subject.